# C. Linked lists. Inserting an element before another

Tags: c, linked-list

Right now I have a program (shown below) that inserts an element (E) after (F). For example if we input `n = 4` and then insert 4 elements `2 3 3 4`, followed by our 'F' value which is `3` and E value which is `6`, the program will edit the list inserting E (6) after F (3), resulting in a list edition from  `2 3 3 4` into `2 3 6 3 4`

I am looking for a way to insert a value 'E' BEFORE an F, not after. Could anyone explain  what changes may be required to this code to achieve the same?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct sarasas { int duomuo; struct sarasas *next, *prev; };
typedef struct sarasas Sarasas;
typedef Sarasas *SarasasPtr;

int main()
{
    int d,i,n,j,e,f;
    SarasasPtr Sar,x,temp,prev=NULL;
    SarasasPtr head= NULL;
    printf("Insert 'n' \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Insert an element: \n");
        scanf("%d",&d);
        x=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof( Sarasas ));
        x->duomuo = d;
        x->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL) {
          head = x;
        } else {
          temp = head;
          while(temp!=NULL) {
              prev = temp;
              temp = temp->next;
          }
          prev->next = x;
        }
    }

   printf("Insert an element after which one you want another element to be inserted\n");
   scanf("%d",&e);
   printf("Insert element which you want to insert\n");
   scanf("%d",&f);

   temp = head;
   int pakeista = 0;

   while(temp!=NULL) {
     //printf("%d",temp->duomuo);
     if (temp->duomuo == e) {
       if (changed == 0) {
         x=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof( Sarasas ));
         x->duomuo=f;
         x->next=temp->next;
         temp->next=x;
         n++;
         changed = 1;
       }
     }
     temp=temp->next;
   }
   Sar = head;
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("Sk Nr. %i: %d\n",i+1,Sar->duomuo);
      Sar = Sar->next;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to check `temp->next->duomuo` instead of `temp->duomuo`

```
while(temp->next!=NULL) {
    if (temp->next->duomuo == e) {
        if (changed == 0) {
            x=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof( Sarasas ));
            x->duomuo=f;
            x->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=x;
            n++;
            changed = 1;
        }
    }
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

I would also suggest that instead of this `changed` thing that you are doing, just break from the loop after you replace. This way your loop won't run more times than it needs to.

```
while(temp->next!=NULL) {
    if (temp->next->duomuo == e) {
        x=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof( Sarasas ));
        x->duomuo=f;
        x->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=x;
        n++;
        break;
    }
    temp=temp->next;
}
```